# getResources().openRawResource Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: android

Uso o comando

```
InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.tabelas);
```

sem problema em um aplicativo.

Só que se for utilizar o mesmo comando num novo aplicativo, acontece o erro

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060001
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060001
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1266)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1181)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1158)
            at rankingfute.ideiainformatica.br.rankingfutebol.PrincipalActivity.onCreate(PrincipalActivity.java:69)
```

A linha 69 é exatamente no comando:

```
InputStream input = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.pontuacao);
```

Qual a diferença, além do conteúdo dos arquivos tabelas e pontuacao?

Comment: Significa que o arquivo `pontuacao.xml` dentro do diretório `res/raw` não foi encontrado. Você verificou a existência dele?

Comment: Existe erros no seu `.xml` ?

Comment: O arquivo está com o nome "pontuacao.txt" como no outro aplicativo está "tabelas.txt".

Comment: O aplicativo chega a executar e não aponta nenhum erro

Comment: É um arquivo texto que manuseio dentro do sistema. Existe alguma restrição quanto a isto? Algo como tamanho de registro ou limite de tamanho?

Comment: Tem uma diferença entre os dois aplicativos: no que funciona e está no Google Play, na frente do nome tabelas.txt não tem nada, e neste novo tem "(nokeys)" na frente do pontuacao.txt. Tentei renomear para só "pontuacao" e deu o mesmo problema. Que nokeys é este?